# Get iframe url after clicking play icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple YouTube iframe videos. I am trying to get url of current clicked iframe. I tried like by giving iframe id but its not work.

Comment: show your effort code

Comment: Any click on iframe occurs in a different window and you can't access that window on cross domain iframe due to *"same origin policy"*. You need to use the youtube iframe api

Comment: Its like $('iframeid').click(function(){var yid=$(this).attr("src"); alert(yid);});

Comment: Thank you charlietfl. Yes I am using youtube iframe api only, but i want to get  url of clicked iframe player only.